# representing a grid board with c

Tags: c

Might be quite a dumb question but I somehow managed to create an empty grid board looking like

```
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 1 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 2 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 3 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 4 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 5 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 6 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 7 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 8 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c;

    printf("%6c", 65);

    for (c = 66; c <= 72; c++) {
        printf("%4c", c);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+");
    for (c = 1; c <= 8; c++) {
        printf("\n%2d |", c);
        for (int d = 1; d <= 8; d++) {
            printf(" . |");
        }
        printf("\n   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+");
    }
}
```

is it possible to allocate each '.' with an according grid location (e.g: B1, G5 etc) in C?

edit : single character replacement would be fine so for example if I want to create a chess board (capital for White, non-capital for Black) it would look something like

```
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 1 | r | b | n | q | k | n | b | r |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 2 | p | p | p | p | p | p | p | p |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 3 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 4 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 5 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 6 | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 7 | P | P | P | P | P | P | P | P |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 8 | R | B | N | Q | K | N | B | R |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

p/P for pawn
r/R for rook
b/B for bishop
n/N for knight
q/Q for queen
k/K for king

Comment: Yes it is possible. What you need is a two dimensional array like `a[8][8]`. The index will be one for rows and another for columns.

Comment: Yes.. to some extent of course. How would you like to use this "B1" location? Can you give an wxample with c code?

Comment: Lots of options. One would be to define an 8x8 2D array (0-7 indices mapped to your designations). Elements can be whatever you need (e.g., `char`).

Comment: @tstanisl I didn't really think that far but for example if I wanna turn that board into like a chess board on A1, the full stop would be replaced to something like BR (black rook).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what values are possible for the fields. This would help to suggest a data type for your array. If you want to have chess pieces displayed as two letters, you could use an `enum` of the possible values (all black and white piece types and "empty") and an 8x8 array of this enum type. When printing the board display you can have a function that translates the `enum` value to a visible string or character array.